# Mongoose - query doc if element not in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am dealing with an issue while querying a notification schema

```js
receiver: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Profile' }],
readBy: [{
    readerId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
                ref: 'Profile', default: [] },
    readAt: { type: Date }
  }]
```

In order to query latest notifications, this is the query I have written:

> **GOAL** is to check if the "**profile.id**" **DOES NOT** exist in the **readBy array** (which means its unread by that user)

```js
const notifications = await Notification.find({
      receiver: profile.id,    // this works 
      readBy: {                // but, adding this returns an empty array 
        $elemMatch: {
          readerId: { $ne: profile.id }
        }
      }
})
```

Would really appreciate the help, stuck here for days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think is easier than we are trying to do.

If you want to know if the element is into the array, then, query looking for it. If the query is empty, it implies that not exists, otherwise yes.

Look this [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zJ5teRgL3ed).

Is a simple query, only check if one document has been received and readed by user `profile.id`.

```js
db.collection.find([
  {
    "receiver": profile.id,
    "readBy.readerId": profile.id
  }
])
```

Please check if the output is as expected or I misunderstood your petition.

In `mongoose` you can use this:

```js
var find = await model.find({"receiver":1,"readBy.readerId":1}).countDocuments()
```

It will return how many documents match the query.

Edit to get documents where `readerId` is not present in the array:

Here, you only need to add `$ne` operator

```js
db.collection.find([
  {
    "receiver": profile.id,
    "readBy.readerId": {
      "$ne": profile.id
    }
  }
])
```

You can check this [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HlpvksmjQG6)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but there is one important thing you missed here, I want readerId NOT to be present in the readBy array. Could you update the answer for that?

Comment: Thanks alot, it worked and the mongo playground was something I wasn't aware of. Its amazing and really helpful.